# solving this integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^\eta  \phi \, d\eta' d\eta$$ $$\phi=\eta-3\eta^3+2\eta^4$$

This is from a fluid mechnanics paper. Can someone solve it and tell me what dn' means since n is a variable already? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occasionally when physicists need a 2nd variable but can't think of another letter, they sometimes put $'$ on the 1st variable to denote that it is indeed a different variable. In this case, they just mean that $\eta'$ is a different variable than $\eta$.

Sometimes Greek letters are intimidating. If we replace $\eta$ with $x$ and $\eta'$ with $y$, we get

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(x-3x^3+2x^4)\,dy\,dx$$

which is a straightforward double integral to evaluate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your answer really helps me. After rederiving the equation, \eta' turns to be \eta in this old paper.